# How can I sort data that is organized in 4-row chunks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have an Excel document with six columns and 57,000 total rows. Each record comprises four rows, that is, each set of four rows goes together. How can I sort this data by one field while keeping the four-row chunks together?

Please let me know if you need more information, this is time sensitive. I will continue to Google search for macros and other ways to transpose this much data, but I think I might be out of options.

Terrible Example:

```
    Row1    Row2    Row3    Row4    Row5    Row6    Row7    Row8
A   Date    1/1/2011        Status: Active      Other Data  Data
B   Time    2:00        Data3   5546        Date2   
C   Name    John Doe                    Time    3:45
D   Data    A456        Notes:  none            
E   Data2   G4561                       
F   Date    1/1/2011        Status: Active      Other Data  Data
G   Time    2:00        Data3   5546        Date2   
H   Name    John Doe                    Time    3:45
I   Data    A456        Notes:  none            
J   Data2   G4561                       
K   Date    1/1/2011        Status: Active      Other Data  Data
L   Time    2:00        Data3   5546        Date2   
M   Name    John Doe                    Time    3:45
N   Data    A456        Notes:  none            
O   Data2   G4561                       
P   Date    1/1/2011        Status: Active      Other Data  Data
Q   Time    2:00        Data3   5546        Date2   
R   Name    John Doe                    Time    3:45
S   Data    A456        Notes:  none            
T   Data2   G4561
```

Comment: What is it you want to do with the data?

Comment: How do you want them sorted?

Comment: So, each record of your data consists of 4 rows, and you want to sort these records while keeping these 4-row chunks together, correct? We're still going to need to know which field(s) you want to use to sort the data.

Comment: I need to keep the "chunks" of data together but I need to sort it all by individual cells. Using the sample above, lets say I need to keep the chunks together but I want to sort by "John Doe". This way John doe chunks will sort and other names will sort likewise..

Comment: That is one nasty set of data! Personally, I'd probably run it through something like Google Refine to reformat the data into single rows before carrying on in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to clean your data before even trying to sort it. Unfortunately, Excel is not the best tool for cleaning data. If you have a decent text editor with regular expression find-and-replace capability (e.g. Notepad++), I'd do the following:

1. Copy your entire table from Excel and paste it into a text editor.
2. If your data is like your sample data (5-row chunks, not 4, and each record starts with `Date`), you could search for the pattern

   `(Date\t.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)`

   and replace all with

   `\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5`

   This should put each record on one line with tab-delimited fields. If this doesn't return what you expect, examine your data, see where the pattern-matching failed, and adjust your pattern accordingly.
3. Finally, copy all the text from the text editor and paste back into Excel (probably on a new sheet). Everything should be aligned in the proper columns so you can sort as you would normally. (If everything isn't aligned properly, start over and fix your search pattern accordingly.)